# Excerpt formatting for Google News Feed

Tags: rss, excerpt, google

We're currently bringing in a Google RSS News Feed using FeedWordPress and it works great.  This issue is that Google uses a defined table structure in their RSS.  The excerpt function has no problem stripping all the tags but it leaves the excerpt cluttered with 3 unwanted snippets of text; Image Caption, Article Title and News Source.

Here is an example;

*msnbc.com1000-year-old hoard of gold coins dug up at Crusades sitemsnbc.comA 1000-year-old hoard of gold coins has been unearthed at a famous Crusader battleground where Christian and Muslim forces once fought for control of the Holy Land, Israeli arch…*

The offending snippets use the "a" and "b" tags.

You can view it live at this link;
http://www.orrvweb.com/?cat=123

Our site uses the Third-Style theme which is a variant of Twenty-Eleven.  We've looked for suitable plugins and tried many of the excellent code samples available of this site thanks to Boutros, Alchymyth and others but we can't get the code to function.

The smoothest thing we've found is the Advanced Excerpt plugin.  It works flawlessly with our site but lacks the exact functionality.  If we could modify it to strip out the tags and text it would be an ideal solution.

Any input or ideas would be greatly appreciated.